# Tkinter '_tkinter.TclError: image "" doesn't exist' when I create a second window with an image

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run the following code, the first window opens up and functions exactly like I expect it to. When I try to open it a second time after the first instance closes, I get a '_tkinter.TclError:  image "" doesn't exist' error and after 2 hours of searching I can't figure out a solution. I just want to make a second window after the first one closes

```
from tkinter import *
from customtkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self, root):
        root.geometry('400x350')
        close_button_image = CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open('assets/close.png'), size=(28, 22))
        self.close_button_image = close_button_image
        close_button = CTkButton(root, text='', image=self.close_button_image, command=root.quit)
        close_button.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    coolman = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

    print('first window closed')

    root = Tk()
    coolman = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The reason I am using a second window is because I don't know of another way to communicate with the main script that the user is done entering information other than when root.mainloop() ends, so I am doing it list this:

```
creds_root = Tk()
creds_window = CredsWindow(creds_root)
creds_root.mainloop()
auth = creds_window.getAuth()

main_root = Tk()
main_window = MainWindow(main_root)
main_root.mainloop()
```

I had a getAuth function that would return what the user typed into an entry box.

Comment: You need to use `Toplevel()` instead of calling `Tk()` again to create additional windows.  Multiple instances of `Tk()` cause all sorts of problems, such as images not working with widgets that belong to a different instance.